# How can I give version to static files instead of timestamp in Next.js

Tags: next.js, timestamp, version

i have next.js project and i want to set version instead of timestamp at all static files.

I have file like this:`/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?ts=1691065023089`
and
I want it to be like this: `/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?v=1.1.1`

Can i do this?